# Multiple sql table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a few tables and a query to select data from those tables but I'm stuck. Tables:

(U_ID is the user id, from another table)
(Made a screenshot since I can't figure out how to paste sql code in here properly)

https://img.bi/#/GvVmkcs!ZJadSHymo1nhAfQkCsEVBGqHloVj9Vw2r2NtXUhY

I'm wondering how I can get the Title, Description, Amount and the Label and Category data in just one query. I have searched for a while now but I just need a simple example to hopefully understand this better. I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Please paste your code and select your code, and press Ctrl+k that will help you paste code properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
SELECT d.Title,
       d.Description, 
       d.Amount, 
       l.Title AS Label, 
       c.Title AS Category 
FROM Data d
JOIN Categories c ON d.CategorieID = c.ID
JOIN Labels l ON d.LabelID = l.ID
```

Same query without table aliases, for a better understanding:

```
SELECT Data.Title,
       Data.Description, 
       Data.Amount, 
       Labels.Title AS Label, 
       Categories.Title AS Category 
FROM Data
JOIN Categories ON Data.CategorieID = Categories.ID
JOIN Labels ON Data.LabelID = Labels.ID
```